# Uninitialized frameSize when opening VideoWriter in OpenCV

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, runtime-error

I'm developing an app to stream a camera over internet by using OpenCV and GStreamer.

I've succesfully done it using Python, and now I'm trying to develop the same app in C++.

I have a problem with the VideoWriter class. It throws an error because there is an assertion to check the frameSize (cap_gstreamer.cpp line 1937), and it says that the parameter is <= 0, so the function fails.

The thing is that the parameter i use when calling the function is ok (640,480), but once inside the function is like it's uninitialized.

I've modified the source code of OpenCV to add a few prints inside the creator and open functions, and all the parameters are ok except the frameSize, which value is random (ex. -396126824, 65535).

I've searched over the internet and i haven't found any similar error.

I'm using OpenCV inside a docker container. OpenCV has been built inside the docker by using the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/opencv && \
    cd ~/opencv && \
    wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip && \
    unzip opencv.zip && \
    rm opencv.zip && \
    mkdir -p build && \ 
    cd build && \
    cmake ../opencv-4.x \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
    -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
    -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=$(python3 -c "from os.path import dirname; from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_h_filename; print(dirname(get_config_h_filename()))") \
    -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var;from os.path import dirname,join ; print(join(dirname(get_config_var('LIBPC')),get_config_var('LDLIBRARY')))") \
    -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$(python3 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())") \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") .. && \
    make -j4 && \
    make install && \ 
    ldconfig
```

The program i use:

```
    string gst_out("appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! "
                   "jpegenc ! "
                   "udpsink host=" + host_ip + " port=" + to_string(port_num));
    cout << "Stream caps: " << gst_out << endl;
    
    /* Open stream */
    Size S = Size((int)640, (int)480);
    printf("Size: w %d, h %d\n", S.width, S.height);

    VideoWriter out(gst_out,                         /* gstreamer pipeline */
                    CAP_GSTREAMER,                   /* gstreamer api */
                    -1,                              /* auto detect codec */
                    FRAMERATE,                       /* framerate */
                    S,                               /* frame size */
                    true);                           /* color=true */
    if (!out.isOpened()) 
    {
        cap.release();
        cout << "Failed to open stream" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
```

The program is compiled by using:

```
g++ streaming_jpeg.cpp -o streaming_jpeg -I /usr/include/opencv4 -L /usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was a compilation error, that i was not linking all the libraries needed for the code to work properly.

Compiling the code as follows solved the issue:

```
g++ streaming_jpeg.cpp -o streaming_jpeg `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```